# Does the keyword extends in java require the derived class to inherit attributes only when a parent class instance is created?

Tags: java

If I have Class A and ClassB extends ClassA . Does a ClassA instance get automatically created When ClassB tries to access attributes,methods etc of ClassA ?

If so what happens if ClassA is an abstract class ??We cannot create instance of abstract class manually but how does JVM handle this scenario or how does ClassB try to access Members of ClassA without an instance of ClassA (being created since its an abstract class)

Comment: Maybe this article will answer to your questions: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2001/jw-1102-java101.html

Answer (score 1):

No ClassA can exist on its own without ClassB.  An instance of a Class must be created via the new operator.  To get an instance of B there must be call in the system somewhere like:

```
new ClassB();
```

If there are only calls like:

```
new ClassA();
```

Then no instance of B exists, so whatever is in ClassB (apart from static methods) is an irrelevance.  I'm ignoring creating new instances via reflection here for simplicity sake.

Inheritance flows down from the parent to the child, so the child can access public, protected or package private methods on the parent (depending on the declared packages of ClassA and ClassB); but the parent cannot access methods on the child.  But methods on the child can be executed in preference to methods on the parent through polymorphism.

I think you should read some of the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: you have it backwards.  ClassB is a ClassA,  If B exists, it is an A and hence implicitly exists.  A can exist without B.  since B extends A.

Answer (score 0):

When a class extends another class in Java, and then gets instantiated, there is only one object that gets created, and that object has all of the methods and variables of its parent's type that it is legally allowed to inherit.  You don't have to instantiate both objects.  Another way of putting it would be this:

Let's say you have class A:

```
public class ClassA{
  public int var1
  private int var2

  public void method1(){...}
  private void method2(){...}
}
```

And also class B:

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA{
  public int newVar1

  public void newMethod1(){...}
}
```

In effect, Class B actually looks like this:

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA{
  public int var1
  public int newVar1

  public void method1(){...}
  public void newMethod1(){...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have have B extends A, whenever you create a B, B *is a* A so an A exists.  It does not exist as a separate object though, B is an A so B has everything an A has.  A can exist without B.

If A is abstract, then you cannot create As.  When you create B, it has all the properites/methods of A since it *is an* A.